# A finite group with three nilpotent subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group with subgroups $H_i\leq G$, for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, such that

- $H_i$ is nilpotent for all $i\in\{1,2,3\}$,
- if $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$ are distinct then $\text{gcd}([G:H_i],[G:H_j])=1$.

Prove that $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: The suggested strategy is to prove every Sylow subgroup of $G$ is normal. If you replace every instance of the word "nilpotent" with the word "solvable" then this is a different (true) exercise, which I have seen the proof of. So perhaps this result could be used. My attempts to mimic the proof have failed.

Comment: This is exercise 672 (pg. 291) in *A Course on Group Theory* by John S. Rose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show each Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal.

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $|G|$. Since the $[G:H_i]$ are relatively prime, $p$ can only divide one of the $[G:H_i]$. Let $\{i,j,k\} =\{1,2,3\}$ and let $P_j$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H_j$. Since $p$ does not divide $[G:H_j]$, $P_j$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Similarly, let $P_k$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H_k$ and conclude it is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. By Sylow's theorem, some conjugate of $H_k$ (WLOG $H_k$ itself) contains $P_j$, so (by the same WLOG) we can take $P=P_j=P_k$. Since both $H_j$ and (that conjugate of) $H_k$ are nilpotent, $P$ is normal in both $H_j$ and (that conjugate of) $H_k$. Let $q$ be a prime dividing $|G|$. Since $\gcd([G:H_j],[G:H_k])=1$, $q$ divides at most one of $[G:H_j],[G:H_k]$, so one of $H_j$, (that conjugate of) $H_k$ contains a Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$. Since both $H_j$ and $H_k$ are nilpotent, we get that $Q$ normalizes $P$. Hence the normalizer $N=N_G(P)$ of $P$ in $G$ contains a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$ for every prime divisor $q$ of $G$, so $[G:N_G(P)]$ is not divisible by any prime $q$, so $N_G(P)=G$ and $P$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: can you explain your second sentence? I can see that if $p$ is a prime dividing $|G|$, then WLOG $p$ does not divide some $[G:H_i]$, hence some $H_i$ contains a $p$-Sylow of $G$

Comment: For my second sentence: Every group, such as $H_i$, has a Sylow $p$-subgroup. If no prime divides $|H_i|$, then $H_j=H_k=G$ and the problem trivializes. Are you talking about my 4th sentence (the one before WLOG)? That sentence contains a proof of its assertion. That proof is not what you wrote.

Comment: I also don't see how the second sentence is true. In particular, fix $i$ and $p$, a prime dividing $H_i$. How do we conclude that $p$ does not divide $[G:H_i]$? However, it does make sense that given $p$ dividing $|G|$, there are at least two distinct $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$ such that $H_i$ and $H_j$ contain a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ (which are conjugate). Then your proof continues.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: I mean the conclusion that $p$ does not divide $[G:H_i]$. I can see that this holds for some $i$, but is it really true for all $i$?

Comment: Gotcha. Let me rewrite.

Comment: Fixed :-) Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: Looks good now. But maybe this would be shorter: $P$ is normalized by $H_j$ and $H_k$, hence by $G = H_jH_k$. (since $G = KL$ if $[G:K]$ and $[G:L]$ are coprime)